# Conditional Formatting Excel Spreadsheet Using Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create 2 conditional formats on a spreadsheet I am manipulating using MS Access 365 VBA. I have created the following code to do this:

```
        Set lrngReport = .Range("$A$2:$" & lstrLastCol & "$" & lintLastRow)
        With lrngReport
        
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            
            'Condition where no record in Donor Comments Modified
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=OR(ISBLANK($J2),$J2<>'Yes')"
             With .FormatConditions(1)
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 243, 109)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .StopIfTrue = False
            End With
        
            'Not reviewed condition
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(ISBLANK($L2),$L2<>'Yes'"
            With .FormatConditions(2)
                .Font.Color = RGB(225, 6, 0)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .StopIfTrue = False
            End With
            
        End With
```

The code fails on 4th line of code

```
 .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=OR(ISBLANK($J2),$J2<>'Yes')"
```

with error ***Invalid procedure call or argument.***

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why try to set Conditional Format and not just set cell color? Will data be edited on this sheet? When I tried your formula just in a cell, tells me the formula has error. Doesn't like the apostrophes, had to use quote mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel won't like the apostrophe delimiters, wants quote marks. Double to escape them as literal text.

`Formula1:="=OR(ISBLANK($J2),$J2<>""Yes"")"`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the double quotes. I have always used chr(34) but I always suspected there was an easier way. Your solution works.

Comment: There is a number of special characters that can be forced to process in code as literal text by doubling them - called escaping.

Comment: Where can I find a list of them?

Comment: I don't know of a comprehensive list of special characters. I've only ever had to escape apostrophe and quote mark - and that was in SQL statements. My understanding of method may be incomplete. Often a backslash is used as an 'escape' character - to force following character to be treated as literal text. That is how some patterns are structured in Access input masking. Then to escape a backslash it would be doubled. Suggest you research topic.